# Macbook trackpad very slow scrolling/panning (disable acceleration?)

Tags: osx, hardware

I'm having issues scrolling in any toolbar or view in Blender on my Macbook Pro 15" (Late 2016).

If I use two fingers, and move them rather slow over the trackpad, almost nothing happens. I need to scroll at a rather high speed, and thus losing precision.

MacOS doesn't work at all like this normally, so it seems to be something with Blender.

Is it possible to completely disable acceleration, so it's 100% linear? That would help a lot!

I made a short GIF to show what it looks like, but it's hard to see how I move my fingers on the track pad, but in the beginning I move them slowly, across the entire pad:
http://i.giphy.com/l3q2GD57N6muCHh3W.gif

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, I'd suggest using a mouse with a scroll wheel, makes life much more easier.

Comment: Thanks, not a solution for me though. I can have a mouse on my desk but sometimes I just grab my laptop and sit in the couch without mouse or anything, and would like the track pad to work.. :)

Comment: The trackpad should work just fine, see my new answer. You don't need a mouse at all, I used my trackpad for quite a while before I bought a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just zoomed in really far. It's not immediately obvious, but Blender zooms and rotates around an invisible point at the center of the view, which you can see by rotating around. Try simply pinch-zooming back out again.

And you do **not** need a regular mouse at all—Blender has excellent multi-touch trackpad support. (Though this doesn't apply to some PC laptop trackpads without multi-touch, although if pinch-zoom and two-finger panning work, you're probably good to go.)